# Drawing in QT5 and Python 3. How to save the image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, drawing

looking at this code example from
https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/bitmap-graphics/#a-bit-of-fun-with-qpainter

Can someone tell me why the background defaults to a black screen which is why I changed the sample code to start with white as the pen color.  Am I missing a property I have to set in this python code to set the background of the label?  I thought labels were transparent backgrounds by default and therefore a grey background.

Finally how do I save the drawn image as a png or similar?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
COLORS = [
# 17 undertones https://lospec.com/palette-list/17undertones
'#000000', '#141923', '#414168', '#3a7fa7', '#35e3e3', '#8fd970', '#5ebb49',
'#458352', '#dcd37b', '#fffee5', '#ffd035', '#cc9245', '#a15c3e', '#a42f3b',
'#f45b7a', '#c24998', '#81588d', '#bcb0c2', '#ffffff',
]

class QPaletteButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(24,24))
        self.color = color
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: %s;" % color)
class Canvas(QtWidgets.QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(600, 300)
        self.setPixmap(pixmap)

        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor('#ffffff')

    def set_pen_color(self, c):
        self.pen_color = QtGui.QColor(c)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.last_x is None: # First event.
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return # Ignore the first time.

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap())
        p = painter.pen()
        p.setWidth(2)
        p.setColor(self.pen_color)
        painter.setPen(p)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())
        painter.end()
        self.update()

        # Update the origin for next time.
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = Canvas()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(l)
        l.addWidget(self.canvas)

        palette = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.add_palette_buttons(palette)
        l.addLayout(palette)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def add_palette_buttons(self, layout):
        for c in COLORS:
            b = QPaletteButton(c)
            b.pressed.connect(lambda c=c: self.canvas.set_pen_color(c))
            layout.addWidget(b)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: The used pixmap has to have ONE color - which is black (#000000). You can [fill](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtGui/QPixmap.html#PySide6.QtGui.PySide6.QtGui.QPixmap.fill) it with something different before you assign it to your "Canvas".

Comment: That was the function I was looking for.  The link you sent is for qt6 but looks the same paramters as 5.  So to save the image there are 2 Save functions, can they both be used?  Or is save(QIODevice *device, const char *format = nullptr, int quality = -1) specific for IOS devices?

Comment: Your PC will not explode if you try it out ... so play around with it.